# Showing Swift 4 Sourcecode on a Wordpress page

Tags: html, swift, wordpress

Can somebody please tell me the best way to display Swift 4 Source code online on a wordpress page? Is there any usefull plugin which can handle Swift 4 or any way to copy from xcode to a RTF > HTML converter? The only plugin I saw is called Crayon, but it's not updated since 2 years.
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any good options, but this article has some suggestions, plus a list of all the plugins available for WordPress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts